# Cython: Change integer with reference

Tags: python, cython

Say I have a simple function that takes as input a pointer to an integer. How do I change the originating integer value?

My idea was as follows:

```
cdef myFunc(int n, int *nnz):

    nnz_int = <uintptr_t>nnz
    nnz_int = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        nnz_int += n
```

but upon reflection, I think I only initially cast the value of *nnz* onto nnz_int, and then change nnz_int, without changing the original nnz. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html):

> Note that Cython uses array access for pointer dereferencing, as `*x` is not valid Python syntax, whereas `x[0]` is.

So this should work:

```
cdef myFunc(int n, int *nnz):
    for i in range(0, n):
        nnz[0] += n
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve by adding `n` to the pointed-to value `n` times; why not simply add `n*n` to it once?